# download images with exif informations from flickr

Tags: flickr

i use the FlickR REST-API to download some images.

For this, i call:
`url_image="http://farm_id.staticflickr.com/server/id_secret_c.jpg;`

the problem is that the downloaded file doesn't include exif data.

Is there a option to get the image with exif  (For example date/time)?

Greetings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get a photo's EXIF info using this method [flickr.photos.getExif](http://www.flickr.com/services/api/flickr.photos.getExif.html)

> Retrieves a list of EXIF/TIFF/GPS tags for a given photo. The calling user must have permission to view the photo

Then just use the info you need.